# How to Login to HPUX VM from HPUX Host machine?

Tags: linux, hp-ux

I installed a VM in HP Unix machine, I can login via SSH.

I need to login via HPUX host machine.

Is there any way doing that?

Comment: try `hpvmconsole -P hostname`  (I am no longer sure about -P or -p , see manual).

Comment: @Archemar '-P' is for hostname and '-p' is for VM ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `hpvmconsole -p <VM ID>` to connect the hpux virtual machine from the host.

To get VM ID type the command `hpvmstatus` in the host and you will get the details of Virtual machine present in the host.